# Updating Craft 3 from ver. 3.0.28 10/23/2018

Tags: updating

I have to update Craft 3 from ver. 3.0.28 10/23/2018, but i got this message:
You’ve reached a breakpoint! More updates will become available after you install Craft CMS 3.0.40.

How can i fix this problem?
Updating from the Terminal is no available with my version.
https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/updating.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manually update to the latest version of Craft `3.0.x`, then update to `Craft 3.1.x`:

- In your `composer.json`, change your Craft package to `"craftcms/cms": "3.0.40",`
- Run `composer update`
- Then in your `composer.json`, change your Craft package to `"craftcms/cms": "^3.0.40",`
- Run `composer update` again

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what it means to be in the breakpoint status, but could you manually change the Craft version in your composer.json and then `composer install`?